# How does function [x] -> ... work

Tags: f#

I was browsing through the source code for FSharp.Data when I came across this line of code

```
let (|Singleton|) = function [l] -> l | _ -> failwith "Parameter mismatch"
```

The `function [l]` is what I don't understand.  More specifically, I don't understand how the `[l]` parameter works.

From experimenting in the FSI, I can determine that it starts a form of pattern matching similar to `match [l] with ...`.  However, I can't figure out how the F# compiler interprets the expression.

What I'd like to know is how it actually works and what rules it follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs on [pattern matching syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx). `function` is a shorthand syntax for taking a single argument and immediately pattern matching:

```
let foo x =
    match x with
    | CaseA -> 1
    | CaseB -> 2
```

Is the equivalent of

```
let foo = function
    | CaseA -> 1
    | CaseB -> 2
```

Note that `function` just adds one argument, it doesn't enforce that there is exactly one argument. For example, this is acceptable:

```
let foo x y = function
  | CaseA -> x + y
  | CaseB -> x - y
```

And is equivalent to

```
let foo x y z = 
  match z with
  | CaseA -> x + y
  | CaseB -> x - y
```

**Edit:**
(For completeness) And as for `[l]`, like Lee said, that's just a match pattern.  Specifically, a structural match pattern on lists which matches lists with a single element, and binds that element to the identifier `l`.  See "List Pattern" [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

It is equivalent to

```
let (|Singleton|) lst =
    match lst with
    | [l] -> l
    | _ -> failwith "Parameter mismatch"
```

so it extracts the element from a single-element list or throws an exception if the list has any other number of elements.